# FileField Validation using Flask not working properly

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm using Flask-WTF to validate my form, but for the FileField, it's not validating properly, it doesn't detect the file.

form.py

```
class addVendorForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Vendor Name',
                       validators=[Required()],
                       description='Eg. Alcatel Lucent'
                       )
    remarks = TextAreaField('Remarks', widget=TextArea())
    profile = StringField('Profile', widget=TextArea())
    file = FileField('Logo',validators=[
           FileRequired()])
    short_hand = StringField(validators=[
       Required()])
    notified = BooleanField()
```

views.py

```
@application.route('/memo', methods=['GET','POST'])
@application.route('/memo/<int:record_id>', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def add_memo(record_id=None):
    if record_id is None:
        record = Vendor()
        form = addVendorForm(request.form)
    else:
        record = Memo.query.filter_by(id=record_id).first_or_404()
        form = addMemoForm(obj=record)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        form.populate_obj(record)
        db.session.add(record)
        upload()
        db.session.commit()

        flash('<strong>Success!</strong> Database Updated.')
        return redirect(url_for('add_memo'))

    return render_template('add-form.html', form=form)
```

And it seems that form object doesn't hold the file.

```
    >>> pp(form.file.__dict__)
    'data': u'',
    'default': None,
    'description': u'',
    'errors': [],
    'filters': (),
    'flags': <wtforms.fields.Flags: {}>,
    'id': 'file',
    'label': Label('file', 'Logo'),
    'meta': <wtforms.form.Meta object at 0x7f9ac40e80d0>,
    'name': 'file',
    'object_data': None,
    'process_errors': [],
    'raw_data': [],
    'short_name': 'file',
    'type': 'FileField',
```

But it's in the request.

```
>>> pp(request.files)
ImmutableMultiDict([('file', <FileStorage: u'cleaned data.xlsx' ('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')>)])
```

What other validation approach can I implement? I just need to implement FileRequired.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
form = addVendorForm(request.form)
```

To

```
form = addVendorForm()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `FileRequired()` validators in the doc.
Have you tried `Required()`?

Comment: File Validations are in file module..
from flask.ext.wtf.file import FileRequired, FileField, FileAllowed

BTW i already solved the problem.. i updated my question with the solution :) thnx btw