# Flask WTF forms file upload: FileRequired() fails validation when upload form is inherited from another form, even though file is present

Tags: python, flask, file-upload, flask-wtforms

I have a form that collects some information, and a form that allows the user to upload a file.  These both work.  Now I'm trying to make a form that combines them and inherits from both.

My file upload form has a FileRequired() validator.  This passes fine when I am accessing just the upload form.  If I have my combined form try to inherit the upload form, validation fails.  However, if I remove the FileRequired() validator, either by removing it from the form it inherits from, or by replacing that field on the combination form, the file uploads fine.  It is only validation that is failing, not the file upload.  I can validate by other means (checking the length of `request.files.getlist('<file>')`, and in fact am already checking that to prevent the user from uploading too many files, so I have a workaround, but I'd like to understand why this is failing.

Here is my views.py:

```
def add_scan(request, exp_id):
    """Add a scan"""
    user_id = str(current_user.get_id())
    if len(request.files.getlist('scan_file')) > 3:
        flash('You can upload up to three files.', 'warning')
        return redirect(url_for('scan.add'))
    for f in request.files.getlist('scan_file'):
        ScanService(user_id, exp_id).add(f)
    flash('You successfully added a new scan.', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('experiment.experiments'))

@blueprint.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add():
    """Access the add scan route and form."""
    form = ScanForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        exp_id = str(session['curr_experiment'])
        return add_scan(request, exp_id)
    else:
        flash_errors(form)
    return render_template('scans/upload.html',scan_form=form)

@blueprint.route('/add_experiment_and_scans', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_experiment_and_scans():
    """Acess the add experiment and scans route and form"""
    form = ExperimentAndScanForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        exp_id = add_experiment(form)
        return add_scan(request, exp_id)
    else:
        flash_errors(form)
    return render_template('scans/experiment_and_scans.html', experiment_and_scan_form=form)
```

Here are the forms:

```
class ExperimentForm(FlaskForm):
    """Experiment form."""

    date = DateField('Date')

    scanner = SelectField('Scanner', choices=[('GE', 'GE'), ('Sie', 'Siemens'), ('Phi', 'Phillips')])

    field_strength = SelectField('FieldStrength', choices=[('1.5T', '1.5T'), ('3T', '3T'), ('7T', '7T')])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Create instance."""
        super(ExperimentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class ScanForm(FlaskForm):
    scan_file = FileField(validators=[FileAllowed(['nii', 'nii.gz', 'zip']), FileRequired()])

    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Create instance."""
        super(ScanForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class ExperimentAndScanForm(ExperimentForm, ScanForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Create instance."""
        super(ExperimentAndScanForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Validation succeeds for `ScanForm` but fails `FileRequired()` with `ExperimentAndScanForm`.  Removing `FileRequired()` from `ExperimentAndScanForm` (either by removing it from ScanForm or replacing the `scan_file` property in `ExperimentAndScanForm`) allows file upload.  Making a new `scan_file` property in `ExperimentAndScanForm` with `FileRequired()` causes validation to fail.

I'm not sure whether it's helpful, but here's the template that renders this form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('scan.add_experiment_and_scans') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">


   <div class="form-group">
        {{experiment_and_scan_form.date.label}}
        {{experiment_and_scan_form.date(placeholder="Date of session", class_="form-control")}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{experiment_and_scan_form.scanner.label}}
        {{experiment_and_scan_form.scanner(placeholder="Scanner", class_="form-control")}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{experiment_and_scan_form.field_strength.label}}
        {{experiment_and_scan_form.field_strength(placeholder="Field Strength", class_="form-control")}}
    </div>
    {{ experiment_and_scan_form.csrf_token }}
    {{ experiment_and_scan_form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ experiment_and_scan_form.scan_file(multiple="multiple") }}
    {{ experiment_and_scan_form.submit }}
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Katie, did you figure this one out?

Comment: This may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253228/filefield-validation-using-flask-not-working-properly

Comment: @AnshumanKumar no.  I just worked around it.  I came back to this question because I was revisiting the same code as validation is failing in a new way (FileAllowed() isn't operating).  I was considering writing a SO question about it, but then I wrote a MRE that works perfectly so I felt like it must be some idiosyncratic detail I'm missing.  Maybe I still will.

Comment: @tserg that was it!  It solved both the past problem and my current problem.